# OPENPYXL: Como obtener el max_row de todas las hojas de un archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

estoy intentando hace varios días de realizar lo siguiente, necesito saber cual es el maximo de filas que tiene cada hoja de un archivo excel existente. Estoy trabajando con openpyxl y un for pero la función worksheets[] no admite listas. El codigo que hice es más o menos lo siguiente:

```
from openpyxl import *

#dirección de salida

out_workbook = load_workbook("Path\\out_book_data.xlsx")

#los nombres de las hojas son conocidos de antemano

id_sheet = ["hoja1","hoja2","hoja3","hoja4"]

for id_sheet in id_sheet:
     sheet = out_workbook.worksheets[id]  # <-----aqui está el problema
     row_count = sheet.max_row
     
print(row_count)
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

para hacer que funcione, al out_workbook.worksheets[i] tienes que pasarle un entero, en vez de una cadena de texto, te recomiendo esto para que te funcione:

```
for i in range(len(id_sheet)):
    sheet = out_workbook.worksheets[i]  # <-----aqui está el problema
    row_count = sheet.max_row
    print(sheet.title)  # Titulo de la hoja
    print(row_count)
    print('La hoja {} tiene {} filas.'.format(sheet.title, row_count))
```

Te explico poco a poco, porqué he hecho esto.

Lo primero de todo, revisa el cómo hacer los for, intenta que no sea el mismo nombre `for id_sheet in id_sheet:`.

Como `out_workbook.worksheets` necesita un integer, he hecho que el for sea con range, para que me devuelva un numero por cada elemento de la lista, `for i in range(len(id_sheet)):`.   `i` va a almacenar esos integers.

Al `out_workbook.worksheets` le pasamos el integer `i`. Ej: `sheet = out_workbook.worksheets[i]`.

Con `sheet.title` obtengo el nombre de la hoja la cual estamos consultando.
Entonces ahora cuando haces el `row_count`, ya sabemos cuantas filas tiene esa hoja.